# Controlling Animation for Points When There Are Missing Values (ggplotly)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I am building a Hans Rosling type visualisation, however, I am having issues with the point movements. I have attached some code that creates an example of my problem, which can be found below.

The best way I can describe it is that whenever there is a missing value, a point has to disappear, therefore a different becomes assigned to a point even if it's in a different group. This logically doesn't make any sense to me.

In the example below, I've removed the Month Year of `Feb 2021` from Clinic A, (i.e. I've removed the whole row), which means that the point disappears as shown in the play animation movement. However, if you notice instead of the Clinic A point simply disappearing, it chooses to keep the Clinic A point, turn into a different Clinic, in this case Clinic B and also convert the surrounding points to different clinics as well. I think it's working off the logic of turn into whatever point is the nearest somehow.

**To really understand what is happening observe the hover of the points from `Jan 2021` to `Feb 2021`**

My question(s) is/are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I specify some sort of group or ID to the points so that they aren't randomly turning into other Clinics.

In my real world scenario I have over 90+ different unique IDs/Clinics so ideally someone would be able to press play and then follow a single point moving across the viz, specifically noticing for any abnormalities in movement. It's extremely difficult to do this, or rather almost impossible, if a given point is converting itself into another point on the fly.

A solution in ggplotly is preferred, but either is fine. If you notice as well, I do have a grouping variable in my original `ggplot()`, which in my mind should be solving this problem, but it **only seems to occur when there is missing data**

Code to Replicate Problem:

```
set.seed(24)


test <- data.frame(Month_Year = rep(paste(month.abb, rep(2021:2022, each = 12), sep = "_"), 4),
           x = abs(rnorm(24*4)),
           y = abs(rgamma(24&4,2,1)),
           Clinic = rep(c("Clinic A", "Clinic B", "Clinic C", "Clinic D"), each = 24))

test$Month_Year <- factor(test$Month_Year, levels = paste(month.abb, rep(2021:2022, each = 12), sep = "_"))


test <- test[-c(2,8,12),]


pt <- test %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, frame = paste0(sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(Month_Year)), Month_Year), text = 
               paste(
                 "RAR:", round(y, 3),
                 "\nMR:", round(x, 3),
                 "\nClinic:", Clinic
               ))) +
  geom_point(shape = 1, color = "firebrick", aes(group = Clinic)) +
  # geom_text(aes(y = NAG + 5)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Rolled Mortality Rate - 3 Month Average", y = "Rolled Admission Rate - 3 Month Average") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 6))



ggplotly(pt, tooltip = "text") %>% 
  animation_opts(
    3000,
    redraw = T
  ) %>% 
  animation_slider(
    currentvalue = list(prefix = "Month Year: ")
  )
```

Comment: I started an issue on the Plotly.R github. Same background but I will connect it here in case I receive an answer there. [Github Link](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2166)